# Why isn't this jQuery selector working?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, hover

JavaScript:

```
<script>

$('#aboutme').on('hover', function(){
    console.log("All the stuff");
    /* $("#aboutmedropdown").css("dispay","block"); */
});

</script>
```

HTML (css inline for now):

```
            <div class="nav">
                <ul class="navlist">
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-home.png" alt="Navigation Home"></a></li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-about.png" id="aboutme" alt="Navigation About"></a>
                        <div id="aboutmedropdown" style="width: 150px; position: absolute; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                            <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-bottom: 5px solid #8cc419;" class="sub_menu">
                                <li style="display: block; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #8cc419;"><a href="#" style="color: #8CC419;">About Me</a></li>
                                <li style="display: block; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; color: #8CC419; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #8cc419;"><a href="#" style="color: #8CC419;">Testimonials</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-yoga.png" alt="Navigation Yoga"></a></li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-pilates.png" alt="Navigation Pilates"></a></li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-fitness.png" alt="Navigation Fitness"></a></li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-media.png" alt="Navigation Media"></a></li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-fitcamp.png" alt="Navigation Fitcamp"></a></li>
                    <li style="position: relative;"><a href="#"><img src="/img/nav-blog.png" alt="Navigation Blog"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I am inspecting the element and VERY CLEARLY see that I have the proper ID on the image I need to hover over -- `#aboutme`.

I am viewing page source and seeing that both my `<script>`, and `jQuery`, are loaded.

Yet, when I hover over the image with the id of `aboutme`, nothing happens in the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your script loading before your HTML?

Comment: Yes, the script is in the head element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use `hover` with the `on`, use `mouseout` OR the equivalent `mouseenter mouseout` (together):

http://jsfiddle.net/deJNU/

Alternatively use the hover method like so:

```
$('#aboutme').hover(function() {
  console.log('hover in');
}, function() {
  console.log('hover out');
});
```

Comment: All 4 answers are missing the point that there is no hover with the on method. Thanks for down voting my correct answer. (Though doc ready is also an issue I didn't notice)

Comment: `Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.` [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('hover', '#aboutme' , function(){
        console.log("All the stuff");
        /* $("#aboutmedropdown").css("dispay","block"); */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Either move the `<script>` tags *after* `#aboutme` (and preferably right before `</body>`) or use:

```
//equivalent to $(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $('#aboutme').on('hover', function () {
```

Comment: Did it that way, still doesn't work, see: livingfit.wordpress.redcow.ca

Answer (score 0):

Try using it this way:

```
$(document).on('hover', '#aboutme', function(){
    console.log("All the stuff");
    /* $("#aboutmedropdown").css("dispay","block"); */
});
```

Comment: I did it that way, still doesn't work, see here: livingfit.wordpress.redcow.ca